# OS X how to check certificate is signature

Tags: macos, ssl, secure-transport

Is there a way to check a certificate is signed by a given root certificate using SecureTransport API similar to OpenSSL X509_verify?

Comment: Certificate is signed by CA certificate which is seldom a root certificate (though it's possible, eg. first-level CA certificates are signed with root certificates of CAs).

Comment: Understand that, i looking for the way to check that using Secure Transport API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On OS X, the API to create and manipulate certificates is the [Certificate, Key, and Trust Services](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/security/conceptual/cryptoservices/KeyManagementAPIs/KeyManagementAPIs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011172-CH11-CHDDDBDF):

> Certificate, Key, and Trust Services is a C API for managing
>   certificates, public and private keys, symmetric keys, and trust
>   policies in iOS and OS X. You can use these services in your app to:
>
> - Create certificates and asymmetric keys
> - Add certificates and keys to
>     keychains, remove them from keychains, and use keys to encrypt and
>     decrypt data
> - Retrieve information about a certificate, such as the
>     private key associated with it, the owner, and so on
> - Convert
>     certificates to and from portable representations
> - Create and
>     manipulate trust policies and evaluate a specific certificate using a
>     specified set of trust policies
> - Add anchor certificates

See for example:

- [SecTrustCreateWithCertificates](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/security/Reference/certifkeytrustservices/Reference/reference.html#jumpTo_51) - Creates a trust management object based on certificates and policies.
- [SecTrustEvaluate](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/security/Reference/certifkeytrustservices/Reference/reference.html#jumpTo_52) - Evaluates trust for the specified certificate and policies.
- [SecTrustSetAnchorCertificates](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/security/Reference/certifkeytrustservices/Reference/reference.html#jumpTo_59) - Sets the anchor certificates used when evaluating a trust management object.

Comment: That is good, but it requires the CA certificate ..., i wan to just verify the signature, AFAIK i must calculate the certificate digest and decrypt the signature using the CA public key and compare both values.

Comment: @José You just want to check if one certificate is signed by another certificate, right? I think you should be able to call `SecTrustCreateWithCertificates` with the first and `SecTrustSetAnchorCertificates` with the second.

Comment: Yes that works, the only issue is that i porting an API that was using just the public key. So i want to preserve the API if possible "boolean Certificate.verify(PublicKey key)" and secure transport APIs require the CA Certificate not just the PublicKey, AFAIK there isn't a way to get the Certificate from the public key

Comment: SecTrustEvaluate is the more close to what i was looking for.